# Placing an image and menu in a header, working with subregio's

Tags: css, image, header

I want to place a picture in the header following by a horizontal menu under the picture.
So I divided the header in two subregio's: img and navbar (html). I get the navbar correct, but the picture does not appear. Anyone an idea? What is the problem in my css-part? Thank you!

```
  <div id="header">
                <div id="img"> 
                </div>
                <div id="navbar">        
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="home.html">home</a></li>
                        <li><a href="band.html">band</a></li>
                        <li><a href="contact.html">contact</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
  </div>
  <!-- end header -->
```

```
#header{
    height: 300px;
    background: black;
}
    #header img{
        background-image: url("img/despikes-header.jpg");
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
    }   
    #navbar{
        color: white;
        font-size: .9em;
        font-weight: normal;
        font-family: Tahoma, Arial, sans-serif;
        font-variant-caps: all-small-caps;
        text-decoration: none;
        float: left;
        text-align: center;        
    } 
    #navbar ul{
        height: auto;
        padding-top: 8px;
        padding-left: 20px;
        }                
    
    #navbar li{
        display: inline;
        padding: 3px;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Apologies for posting as an answer rather than comment, however my rep isn't high enough to comment yet.

Your CSS is incorrect.

Rather than `#header img`, you should be using `#header #img` and go from there.

You may well need to apply a height (and perhaps `background-size` to that styling too, otherwise the `div id="img"` doesn't know what size to be.

As an aside, you should probably look to avoid using ids and use classes instead.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks a lot for helping me out. But unfortunately it doesn't work. If I place the image under #header it appears. If I place it under #img or #header img or #header #img it doesn't appear. I applied the background-size as you suggested!

Comment: Sorry if I wasn't clear.
If you try changing your CSS from
`#header img{`
to
`#header #img{`
and add a `height: 200px;` to it.

Other than change the image being used, I've only added the `#` in front of img and the height here: https://codepen.io/kiwimind/pen/KKeRdNp

Comment: It's so friendly of you. It was clear. I tried it ... but no succes

Comment: It finaly works :-)! Just #img{ ... in combination with width and heigth. Another thanks for helpin! me out. Div img has a unique id. So no need to combine with header.

Comment: @Maud you're welcome. Either `#header #img {}` or just `#img {}` should work.

You might want to look into classes at some point, but that's for another day.